# Why does the area under a Maxwell speed distribution graph equal unity?

Tags: probability, kinetic-theory

I am learning the "Kinetic Theory of Gases", in which I have now come across the "Maxwell speed distribution" graph, which I have attached here:

[image: Maxwell speed distribution graph]

My copy of "Resnick and Halliday" states that the area under each curve has a numerical value of unity. The area under the curve is given by the following integral, yes?

$$\int_0^{\infty} P(\nu) d\nu$$

My doubt is this; how does this area equal unity? If the y-axis represents the *fraction* of molecules possessing a given speed(plotted on the x-axis), doesn't the product of the two give the expected value, viz. most probable speed?

Please do share your insights. MUCH thanks in advance :) Regards.

Comment: I think I see the issue. It looks like $\int P(v) dv$ is multiplying together $P(v)$ and velocity. But the $dv$ is just the integration variable; it tells you you're integrating over velocity, but it doesn't _multiply_ by velocity. To calculate the expected value, you would calculate $\int P(v) v dv$ instead.

Comment: The expression P(v) is intended to mean the probability density function, and the integral over all values of 'v' means the probability of a velocity in the range of zero to infinity.   That range contains ALL possible values of velocity, so that probability is 1 (or, 100%).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product $P(v)dv$ is the fraction of the molecules with velocities in the range from velocity $v$ to velocity $v+dv$.

Think of it as a histogram. If we divide up the velocity range in groups of some small velocity $dv$ we'd get a histogram looking something like:

[image: Velocity histogram]

For each column the area of column is $P(v)dv$, and this gives the fraction of the molecules in that velocity range. If we add up all the columns we have to get unity because the total fraction of all the molecules is one.

If you now imagine making $dv$ smaller and smaller the columns in the histogram get thinner and in the limint of $dv\rightarrow 0$ we get a smooth curve like the ones you show.

Comment: Why does $P(v)dv$ give the fraction of molecules? I understand what knzhou has stated in his comment but if that is not the correct way to think about this, how does the product give the fraction of molecules? This, I think, is the main fault in my understanding of this concept. Can you please clear this up?

Comment: @KaumudiHarikumar: that's how the function $P(v)$ is defined. It's a [probability distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function).

Comment: Can you please explain to me why we are required to multiply the value on the y-axis with $dv$ to obtain the fraction of molecules possessing a speed in the range $V$ to $V+dv$? (I have only just graduated high school so please use a simple analogy)

Comment: @KaumudiHarikumar: suppose we are looking at people's height and our function $P(h)$ is the probability density for the height. Suppose we have 1000 people and 10 of them have a height between 1.9 and 2m. In this case $dh=0.1$m and we want $P(h)dh$ to equal 10/1000 i.e. 1% of people have a height in this range. Now suppose we increase $dh$ to 0.2m so our range is 1.8 to 2m. You'd expect roughly twice as many people to be in this range, and since $dh$ has doubled we expect $P(h)dh$ to double as well. Does this example help?

Comment: Okay. Exactly what does a single point on the curve correspond to?

Comment: @KaumudiHarikumar: a single point on the $P(v)$ curve is the probability that the velocity is **exactly** $v$. But this probability is zero because to be exactly $v$ means that the velocity is $v \pm 0.00\text{-infinite no. of zeros-}001$. Unless you have an infinite number of molecules no molecule will ever have a velocity of exactly $v$. And this matches with our meaning for $P(v)dv$. If we set $dv=0$, i.e. a point, then the product $P(v)dv$ is zero as we expect.

Comment: Okay, so if I am to add up $P(v)$ for every point on the curve(as my intuition asks me to do, to find the net probability (1)), I will get a value of...0?

Comment: @KaumudiHarikumar: How are you going to add up values of $P(v)$? You could say well I'm going to add $P(0)+P(0.01)+P(0.02)+$ and so on, but when you do that you're effectively setting $dx=0.01$ because the points you're adding up are spaced by $0.01$. The number you would eventually get would be $1/0.01$ i.e. $1/dx$.

Comment: But if I add these values, what will I obtain? Why won't it be 0, according to the argument that you gave in your previous comment?

Comment: @KaumudiHarikumar: I feel as though are talking past each other. If you want to discuss this I am [in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) at the moment. I'm not sure how useful it is to continue the dicussion here.

Comment: Yes, I also feel that we really are talking past each other. I would love to clear this up in the chat/discussion room but isn't that chat for some other topic? Aren't everyone else talking about different things?

Comment: @KaumudiHarikumar: we can discuss anything in the chat room. Just click [this link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).

Comment: @JohnRennie I do not think that your statement "a single point on the P(v) curve is the probability that the velocity is exactly v" is correct because $P(v)$ is not a probability $P(v)$ has units.  For a lot of students when meeting $P(v)$ for the first time the confusion arise because it is assumed that it $P(v)$ is a probability.  The probability function is the area under the $P(v)$ against $v$ graph.

Comment: @Farcher: Yes, I agree. I'll revisit the answer. If anyone is interested [we discussed this in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32179413#32179413) and successfully resolved it.

Comment: @JohnRennie I have read the deliberations in the chat room. Well done. I think that you have another satisfied customer.

Comment: @Farcher Definitely! :D

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps knowing something about the properties of the probability distribution function $P(v)$ will help?

What you are looking for is a way to describe the distribution of the speeds of the atoms in a gas.

The first thing to note is that you cannot use the probability of an atom having a given speed $v$.
The reason for this is that you can choose a value of the speed $v$ to as many significant figures as you like and then to I hope you realise that you will never find an atom with **exactly** that speed.

So you have resort to finding a function $f(v)$ which describes the probability of finding atoms in a certain range of speeds.

Now jump ahead and consider how to make that function $f(v)$, which describes the distribution of the speeds of the atoms in a gas, useful.

It would be useful to be able to plot the graph of the function $f(v)$ against speed (v) and make the area under the graph equal to $1$ .
The reason for doing this in the area under the $f(v)$ against $v$ graph will represent the probability of finding an atom in the range of speeds  $v=0$ to $v=\infty$ which must be $!$.

Probability has no units but the product $f(v) \;v$ has the units of speed so we define another function $g(v) = \dfrac {f(v)}{1\; \text{m s}^{-1}}$ which has the units s m$^{-1}$ to get over this problem.
Please note the units of $P(v)$ in your graph.

So now the integration $\displaystyle \int^\infty _0 g(v) \;dv= 1$ results in a numerical value with no units. 
Note that the function $g(v)$ has been chosen to have the property that the area is $1$.

The area under the $g(v)$ against $v$ graph can now be used to find the probability of the speed of an atom being between any two speed, $v_1$ and $v_2$ and that is $\displaystyle \int^{v_2} _{v_1} g(v) \;dv$.

The function $g(v)$ is given a name, the probability distribution function, and a symbol $P(v)$.

Having gone through all this, how to describe the function $P(v)$ in words?
For example what does the value $P(400) = 0.0021 \;\text{s m}^{-1}$ on your $T= 300$ K graph mean?

It means that the probability of finding an atom with a speed between $400 \; \text {m s}^{-1}$ and $401 \; \text {m s}^{-1}$ is approximately $0.0021 \times 1 = 0.0021$ whereas for the same speed range the probability for the gas at $80$ K is approximately $0.0008$.

As the range of speeds gets smaller the approximation gets better and furthermore the ratio of the two probability distribution functions at the two temperatures gives you the ratio of the probabilities of finding the speeds of the atoms at the two temperatures being (around) $400 \; \text {m s}^{-1}$.